# How to determine which method is taking so long when initializing a Spring application

Tags: java, performance, debugging, intellij-idea, profiling

I'm familiar with the standard debugging practices and those are not working in this case since I cannot follow step by step a Spring application manually. There are many processes that take place, when the service is initialized like trips to the DB, beans initialization, etc. Is there a profiling tool that could catch how much time a method takes and where exactly is the problem that causes the app to stop doing anything for a long period of time? I can use any IntelliJ Idea Ultimate tools, if that would help. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I personally used [JProfiler](https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html) for a while to test where an application I wrote was slowing down on during rendering. It allows you to see the time it takes to run methods, how often they are called and a bunch of other information that could be really useful for you in this case!

Answer (score 0):

Turn on debug level logging, so you can following the Spring initialization process, e.g. do one of the following:

- Add JVM option to `java` command:

  ```
  -Dlogging.level.org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory=DEBUG
  ```
- Add JVM option to `mvn` command:

  ```
  -Dspring-boot.run.arguments=--logging.level.org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory=DEBUG
  ```
- Add option to `application.properties` file:

  ```
  logging.level.org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory = DEBUG
  ```
- Add option to `application.yml` file:

  ```
  logging.level.org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory: DEBUG
  ```

I would recommend one of the last two, just remember to remove or comment out the option when done.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that one. If the problem is in the Spring init that would help. Otherwise I will have to follow a more generic approach

Comment: @Galya Your question did say *"when initializing a Spring application"*, so the problem *is* in the Spring init. The extra logging provided by this will log every bean being created, along with a timestamp, so if the log shows a delay when creating a particular bean, then that bean would be your problem.